# Force users to uninstall chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, uninstallation

I built a quick one-off chrome extension about a month ago during the SOPA craziness.  Long story short, it unblacked Wikipedia, so that people who needed it could get some work done.

Once the blackout was over, I updated the app to no longer have any effects on any websites.  I also modified it so it would put a console.log() saying essentially "The blackout is over.  SOPA is still important, but you should uninstall this extension".

Unfortunately, a month later, I'm still showing that 90% of the original users have the extension installed.  Certainly it doesn't have that large of a footprint, but as a developer I feel it's my duty to not let my extension become crapware on my user's computers.

Is there a way to forcefully uninstall a chrome extension?  Is there some way that would be unintrusive to the user that I could inform them that they should uninstall the extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update the extension so that it requires the 'management' permission, and then use [chrome.management.uninstall](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html#method-uninstall) to make the extension uninstall itself.

Comment: Oh really?  Well, that's incredibly interesting.

Comment: It's a good solution: users would either deny the additional permissions, which would disable the extension, or allow them, in which case the extension would be removed. Clever. :)

Comment: It's unfortunate that there's no way to wind down and disable an add-on without requiring a user to accept the added permission to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is no way in this situation. Unless

1. If your extension makes **a request to a server** that you can access, such as a web service from you, maybe you can send an alert to your users.
2. If auto update is enabled in your extension, **you can update your extension**. In your updated version, **you can show users an alert** (shouldn't be a real javascript alert. Some kind of alert) to uninstall your extension.
3. If auto update is enabled, **you may update your extension to do nothing**. Just a console.log message.

Comment: I'd suggest updating your extension to request `notification` permissions, and using those permissions to pop up a desktop notification with uninstallation instructions, once. See http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html for details.

Comment: Option 3 is the route I've gone already.  I would like to do what @MikeWest has suggested, but is that obtrusive to the user?  I'm trying to imagine what I would think if an app did that to me.  I guess it's just weighing which is worse - bothering the user, or getting crapware off their computer.

Comment: For your case, I don't think it is very obtrusive for the user.